# Is it possible to access a method's variable that isn't a property of the object?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

So I have a class that I can't (not allowed to) modify and I need to extend one of the methods. The problem is that my child class's method needs to use a variable set locally in the parent method I'm extending. Here's what I mean:

```
class ParentClass 
{ 
    function process_data() 
    {
        $data['x'] = "This is some data.";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

    function process_data() {
        parent::process_data();
        $clean_data = strtolower(parent::$data);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the local `$data` variable from the parent method without modifying the parent class in any way?

Comment: nope, the `$data` is defined inside the `process_dat()` scoop and is not returned either so there is no way to access it.

Comment: Even if my method is an extension of the parent method?  That's disappointing.

Comment: if the parent class `process_data()` method had `return $data['x.....` your code would have work just fine!

Comment: I figured. I was just hoping there was some kind of scope resolver (like global) for this type of situation.  The parent method does call  another method and passes it the variables I need, so I think I can just extend that instead.  Not as clean, makes me feel like I'm piggy-backing, but sometimes that's the way it goes.

Comment: You can use something like [`runkit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) to redefine a function definition.

Comment: Did I miss something or you can just copy the source code of ParentClass::process_data() to ChildClass::process_data() and change the code how you wish (use $data etc.) without parent::process_data() call?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it to be in the global scope, but ... this is OOP. Why don't you just make it a property?

Comment: I'm writing a customization to the software and one of the requirements is that the core code can't be modified, only extended. I could extend the method and simply copy the entire contents instead of calling the parent method, and then make the changes I need, but I wanted to confirm that I wasn't missing some feature of php oop that would facilitate my goal.  I'm writing the original developers this week to let them know that they need to make it a property.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, unless they have intentionally put this `$data` var in the local scope - I guess you'll be having a lot more conversations with them. Good luck.